# How can I timestamp IIS Web deployment packages made with Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: iis, web-deployment, webdeploy

Right now I can deploy  a package to a directory but we may want to have a weekly deployment package so is there some easy way to append the filename of the deployment zip file with a timestamp ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make MSBUILD script which makes such deployment package for you:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="4.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Release</Configuration>
    <BasePackageName>TestPackage</BasePackageName>
    <BuildTime>$([System.DateTime]::Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss"))</BuildTime>
    <DeployDir Condition=" '$(DeployDir)' == '' ">$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Output</DeployDir>
    <PackageFileName Condition=" '$(PackageFileName)' == '' ">$([System.String]::Format("{0}\{1}_{2}.zip", $(DeployDir), $(BuildTime), $(BasePackageName)))</PackageFileName>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <Target Name="CheckProperties">
    <Error Condition=" '$(ProjectFile)' == '' " Text="ProjectFile is required." />
  </Target>

  <Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="CheckProperties">
    <!-- Deploy using windows authentication -->

    <Message Text="Creating $(PackageFileName)" />
    <MSBuild Projects="$(ProjectFile)"
        Targets="WebPublish"
        Properties="Configuration=$(Configuration); WebPublishMethod=Package; DeployOnBuild=true; PackageFileName=$(PackageFileName);"
    />
    <Message Text="$(PackageFileName) successfully created!" />
  </Target>
</Project>
```

It will create in deploy dir (DeployDir script parameter, with $(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\Output as default value) files:

- 2014-06-23-17-04-21_TestPackage.zip
- 2014-06-23-17-04-21_TestPackage.deploy.cmd
- 2014-06-23-17-04-21_TestPackage.deploy-readme.txt
- 2014-06-23-17-04-21_TestPackage.SetParameters.xml
- 2014-06-23-17-04-21_TestPackage.SourceManifest.xml

This script requires ProjectFile parameter to be set.
To run this MSBUILD script you can use the following bat file (let's save MSBUILD script in the same directory with name deploy.xml) or use autobuild server.

```
set WORK_DIR=%~dp0
pushd %WORK_DIR%
set VSTOOLS="%VS120COMNTOOLS%"
if %VSTOOLS%=="" goto vsnotfounderror
call "%VSTOOLS:~1,-1%vsvars32.bat"
if errorlevel 1 goto end

msbuild.exe deploy.xml "/p:ProjectFile=%1"
if errorlevel 1 goto end

:vsnotfounderror
echo "Can't find Visual Studio 2013"

:end
popd
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%
```

Now run this script:

```
deploy.bat TestSolution\TestWebApplication.csproj
```

Comment: what for do you need 'call "%VSTOOLS:~1,-1%vsvars32.bat"' line?

Comment: @Isantipov - to initialize environment with correct paths and variables (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1700bbwd.aspx).